# Print from CMS to JavaScript Object

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working on a project that uses an old, custom-built CMS to run a website that is quite heavy in JavaScript. Throughout a given template (.jsp), they're using Java conditionals to set up inline JavaScript variables and functions. They're also making external JavaScript and CSS requests all over the place. This has led to some very poor performance, as you can imagine.

I'm trying to organize things so that most of the JavaScript is in external files, being called before the closing body tag. One of the tricky parts of this is externalizing inline JavaScript when they're using Java to create variables. As far as i know, I can't drop bits of Java into a .js file.

The solution I've come up with is to create an object into which Java can print some variable values, and then pass them on to the external JS files. For example:

```
var foo = new Object;
foo.bar = <s:property value="bar" escape="false"/>;
```

Then in the external file:

```
(function(){
    console.log(foo.bar);
}());
```

From a conceptual standpoint, does this seem like a valid solution? It seems to work fine, but I'm wondering if there's a specific reason that I shouldn't do it this way. Please excuse my wording if I'm not using the proper terms.

Comment: This is my preferred solution when it gets hairy as well. Works nicely with CMS I use, WordPress has some [built-in functionality](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script) to do this so I'd say it's common practice.

Comment: Thanks for the response! It makes sense to me, but it seemed like one of those things where there might be a programmatic reason not to do it.